# How can I retrieve a record with its external id in code-behind

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

How can I find a record in database using its External Id?

Let's say I have the following record in my data file:

```
<record model="product.product" id="product_to_find"> ... </record>
```

How can I retrieve it in code-behind?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/OdooRPC/tuto_browse.html), you just have to call `odoo.env.ref(external_id)`.

For exemple:

```
my_product = self.env.ref('product.product_to_find')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the reference of xml id using env.

```
product_id = self.env.ref('product.product_to_find').id
```

and below is the alternative way to get the record by xml id

```
ir_model_obj = self.pool['ir.model.data']
product_recs= ir_model_obj.get_object_reference(self._cr, self._uid, 'product', 'product_to_find')
product_rec = product_recs and product_recs[1] or False
```